# In R, Python or Stata: How to delete all files in all subfolders

Tags: python, r, stata

I have a folder with multiple subfolders (with more subfolders in those) where different specifications of datasets are saved (sometimes sliced and diced).

I am afraid that some legacy files in there will mess things up when I aggregate files together. So I am looking for a command to delete all files in all subfolders of a given folders (but not the subfolders them selves). Is there a simple way of doing this in `R`, `Python` or `Stata` without having to create a list of all applicable subfolders first?

Comment: So you have a top level folder with subfolders, and you want to delete all the files in these subfolders but keep the subfolders? With questions like these its always good to give a concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Python**

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/root/folder/'):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
        os.remove(file)
```

**R**

```
root_dir <- "/path/to/root/folder"
files <- paste(root_dir, list.files(root_dir, recursive = T), sep="/")
for(file_path in files){
  file.remove(file_path)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the concise answer!

Comment: @SAFEX you are welcome! :)